# How to install Ubuntu or BackTrack Linux on iMac

Tags: linux, mac, imac, backtrack

I have an Intel based iMac 2010 21.5" and I would like to install Backtrack (preferably) or Ubuntu.

Every time I try to install one of the two, I get a black screen when the installer loads the video drivers. I have tried everything I found on searching on the internet but haven't resolved my problem.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which video drivers? If you don't mind 1024x768 and poor OpenGL support, you can use the default VESA drivers that work everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you want but might help.  I have my macbook set up as a tri boot with backtrack now and it works great.  Originally I tried to just just do OSX and backtrack on a bootcamp partition and ran into all kinds of problems with drivers (all though I've been told its possible.  However I found that if I have windows and then install ubuntu through windows I pull all the drivers over 100%.  I also run many Linux distro in vm's on the windows partition and they run 100%.